# Bash - redirect stdout and stderr to files with background process

Tags: python, linux, bash, init

I've created a simple init script for an application I'm building. The start part of the script looks like this:

```
user="ec2-user"

name=`basename $0`
pid_file="/var/run/python_worker.pid"
stdout_log="/var/log/worker/worker.log"
stderr_log="/var/log/worker/worker.err"

get_pid() {
    cat "$pid_file"
}

is_running() {
    [ -f "$pid_file" ] && ps `get_pid` > /dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    if is_running; then
        echo "Already started"
    else
        echo "Starting $name"
        cd /var/lib/worker
        . venv/bin/activate
        . /etc/profile.d/worker.sh
        python run.py  >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
        echo $! > "$pid_file" 
        if ! is_running; then
            echo "Unable to start, see $stdout_log and $stderr_log"
            exit 1
        fi
        echo "$name running"
    fi
```

I'm having trouble with this line:

```
python run.py  >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
```

I want to start my application with this code and redirect the outputs to the files specified above. However, when I include the `&` to make it run in the background, nothing appears in the two log files. BUT, when I remove the `&` from this line, the log files get data. Why is this happening?

Obviously I need to run the command to make it run as a background process in order to stop the shell waiting.

I am also sure that the process is running when I use the &. I can find it with a `ps -aux` :

```
root     11357  7.0  3.1 474832 31828 pts/1    Sl   21:22   0:00 python run.py
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? :)

#### Short Answer:

Yes. add `-u` to the python command and it should work.

```
python -u run.py  >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
```

#### Long Answer:

It's a buffering issue (from `man python`):

```
   -u     Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout
          and  stderr  in  binary  mode.   Note that there is internal buffering in xreadlines(), readlines() and file-
          object iterators ("for line in sys.stdin") which is not influenced by this option.  To work around this,  you
          will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()" inside a "while 1:" loop.
```